# Which function do I use

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am having trouble figuring out how to look for data in a column and return the value of the corresponding row. The lookup function will find what I need however will not return multiple values within that column.

[image: Example]

I want to know how to look for all the "V" in column and return Pete and James

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try simple:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, B2:B="V")
```

if you want it in one row:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B="V"))
```

if you want it in one cell:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A2:A, B2:B="V"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much I also used the =IFERROR() function to get rid of the #NA feature.

Comment: you can use shorter `IFNA()` instead of `IFERROR()`